# How to trick an Excel function that wants a column as input to accept a list of values as if these were in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to use the XIRR(values,timestamps) function. It expects two columns as input otherwise it won't work.

Let's say this example works just fine:

|  | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -12000 | 1900/01/01 |
| 2 | -12000 | 1901/01/01 |
| 3 | 25000 | 1902/01/01 |
| 4 | **=XIRR(A1:A3,B1:B3)** |  |

It will return a proper result in the field A4.

Now the problem: I want it to work if the last value of the list is for example not in A3 but in C3 instead, e.g.:

|  | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -12000 | 1900/01/01 |  |
| 2 | -12000 | 1901/01/01 |  |
| 3 |  | 1902/01/01 | 25000 |
| 4 | **=XIRR((A1:A2 C3),B1:B3)** |  |  |

So the first input argument for the `XIRR` function would be a combination of values in `column A` and `C`. But of course the function does not accept this. I am not allowed to just combine values to a *virtual `column`* as input argument.

The obvious solution *"Just copy the value of `C3` to `A3` and then run the command `=XIRR(A1:A3,B1:B3)`"* does not work for me. In reality there is an array with something like 1000x1000 values for "`C3`". But "`C3`" should always represents the last element for the `XIRR` function input argument `value`.

What I am basically asking for is a solution to dynamically and artificially combine a list of values from different positions in a work sheet to some sort of imaginary/temporary column, which can be used as valid input argument within a function call (of a function that expects a column as input) *without actually having to create the column within the excel sheet*. In other words I'd need a function, which can combine values to a virtual column, which will be accepted as argument by the `XIRR` function.

Is this possible somehow? Is there a proper alternative?

Comment: `=XIRR(IF(A1:A3=0,C1:C3,A1:A3),B1:B3)` to be entered as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) if you don't have dynamic arrays

Comment: Or, more simply `=XIRR(A1:A3+C1:C3,B1:B3)` if the same cell in the other column is always empty (also an array formula if you have legacy Excel)

Comment: @SpectralInstance: Your soluation doesn't work and I assume you did not understand my question. I don't want to add A1:A3 and C1:C3 then my result would be just totally wrong... and also A1:A3 is never zero. I need a function call, which makes it possible to split the input argument from two different sources instead of being all in one column. I need the first "N-1" elements from Column A and the Nth element must be from Column C. But this requirement is not fulfilled by your suggestions, which will either chose Column A or Column C (but not combine it in the way I need it) or add both ...

Comment: I think @SpectralInstance is not the only one who does not understand your question. ;)

Comment: Was it really so complicated? @user11222393 perfectly understood it... and he has the perfect solution. :-)

Comment: `=XIRR(IF(ROW(A1:A3)<3,A1:A3,C3),B1:B3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Excel 365 you can use `VSTACK`: [vstack](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vstack-function-a4b86897-be0f-48fc-adca-fcc10d795a9c) to make an array:

[image]

Use it as value input instead of range. Result:

[image]

Comment: You're a hero... :-). That's exactly what I needed... a function, which allows to stack arbitrary sources/fields to a sort of virtual/temporary column array, which can be passed to another function instead of having to create a real column with all the numbers. I considered Google Search, Chat GPT and similar and never ever read about VSTACK. Why is Excel so extremly not intuitive and so extremly bulky? And searching for solutions around Excel is almost as bad as trying to figure out by yourselve. I just don't get it. However, thank you a 1000 times. Exactly what I was looking for...